# Google vertex endpoint is unavilable when deploying new model

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Every night we train a new model, and deploy it (in Flaks) to an existing endpoint. The Flask code is (simplified) as:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

def load_models()
   """
    Load new model from google cloud storage
   """
   .
   .
   return model
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.ensure_ascii = False
MODELS_ARE_LOADED = False
model = load_models()
MODELS_ARE_LOADED = True



@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
     data = request.get_data()
     predictions = model.predict(data)

     return {"predictions":predictions}


@app.route('/health', methods=["GET"])
def health():
    if not MODELS_ARE_LOADED:
        raise BadRequest("Models are not loaded yet")
    return "OK"
```

which works fine.
The issue is that it seems like the old model is removed before the new model is ready, leading to the endpoint being unavailable for a few minutes.

The check `MODELS_ARE_LOADED` seems to work locally i.e returns the error message when the models are not loaded, and as far as I understand the endpoint is not considered "ready" before it's healthy.

I would assume that adding a new model the traffic wouldn't go to the new model before it is healthy, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Hi CutePoison, Can you confirm if you have been facing any error message while deploying a new model ?

Comment: No errors  at all. The deployment process works fine